# XCode (4.6.3) invokes TiffUtil in the Copy Resources Phase

Tags: ios, xcode, resources, copy, bundle

Does anyone know why Xcode (4.6.3) would start TiffUtil in the Copy Resources Phase instead of just copying PNG files to the bundle using CpResource . I'm now ending up with some normal PNG icons and splash screens and a few tiffs. I've checked the images, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with them.

Thanks,
Daniel Dekkers

[image: TiffUtil]

Comment: From where you got xcode (6.4.3) version. xcode 5.0.2 is the latest stable version.

Comment: Are there .tiff files in the project?

Comment: No .tiff files in the project. I'm always careful upgrading Xcode if things work (which they don't, -sigh-).

Comment: And I have Lion, I think XCode 5+ needs Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this last week! 
The problem was in the build settings.

> Combine High Resolution Artwork COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES
>
> Combines image files at different resolutions into one multi-page TIFF
>   file that is HiDPI compliant for Mac OS X 10.7 and later. Only image
>   files in the same directory and with the same base name and extension
>   are combined. The file names must conform to the naming convention
>   used in HiDPI. [COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES]

It wants to take your x.png and x@2x.png and turn it into a multi-page TIFF. But since this option isn't valid for iOS, none of your images will work correctly. 
So, in the build settings, try and find "Combine High Resolution Artwork" and turn it off. If its not in there, you can also search for the COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES flag and turn it off.

Comment: You, cjwirth, are a life saver. That was it.